# VS2015 Type Guards Inspection Error "Cannot resolve"

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

In my TypeScripte project I have this method:

```
function setIntro(intro: HTMLElement|HTMLElement[]) {
    if (intro instanceof Array) {
        console.log(intro.length);
    }
}
```

The project compiles well but Visual Studio highlights `.length` because it cannot be resolved.

Can we add support for Type Guards to VS? I don't want to disable inspections.

Comment: this sounds more like a bug for VS2015 than something we could help you with here. :)

Comment: This works perfectly for me: Visual Studio 2015 (14.0.2472.00 Update 1) and TypeScript tools version 1.8.0.0.